# How to vectorize a json dictionary using R wrapped in python?

Tags: python, json, r, machine-learning, rpy2

High level description of what I want: I want to be able to receive a json response detailing certain values of fields/features, say {a: 1, b:2, c:3} as a flask (json) request. Then I want to convert the resulting python_dict into an r dataframe with rpy2(a single row of one), and feed it into a model in R which is expecting to receive a set of input where each column is a factor in r. I usually use python for this sort of thing, and serialize a vectorizer object from sklearn -- but this particular analysis needs to be done an R.

So here is what I'm doing so far.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import STAP
model = os.path.join('model', 'rsource_file.R')
with open(model, 'r') as f:
string = f.read()
model = STAP(string, "model")

data_r = robjects.DataFrame(data)
data_factored = model.prepdata(data_r)
result = model.predict(data_factored)
```

the relevant r functions from rsource_code are:

```
prepdata = function(row){
 for(v in vars) if(typeof(row[,v])=="character") row[,v] = as.factor(row[,v], levs[0,v])
 modm2=model.matrix(frm, data=tdz2, contrasts.arg = c1,xlev = levs)
}
```

where contrasts and levels have been pre-extracted from an existing dataset likeso:

```
#vars = vector of columns of interest
load(data.Rd)
for(v in vars) if(typeof(data[,v])=="character") data[,v] =    as.factor(data[,v])
frm = ~ weightedsum_of_things #function mapped, causes no issue
modm= (model.matrix(frm,data=data))
levs = lapply(data, levels)
c1 = attributes(modm)$contrasts
```

calling prepdata does not give me what I want, which is for the newly dataframe(from the json request data_r) to be properly turned into a vector of "factors" with the same encoding by which the elements of the data.Rd database where transformed.

Thank you for your assistance, will upvote.

More detail: So what my code is attempting to do is map the labels() method over a the dataset to extract a list of lists of possible "levels" for a factor -- and then for matching values in the new input, call factor() with the new data row as well as the corresponding set of levels, levs[0,v].

This throws an error that you can't use factor if there isn't more than one level. I think this might have something to do with the labels/level difference? I'm calling levs[,v] to get the element of the return value of lapply(data, levels) corresponding to the "title" v (a string). I extracted the levelsfrom the data set -- but referencing them in the body of prep_data this way doesn't seem to work. Do I need to extract labels instead? if so, how can I do that?